# How can i delete string in variable powershell?

Tags: string, powershell

I have a log file like this :

```
[2021/04/13 18:21:57.577+02:00][VERBOSE] Finished: 0 file(s), 5.23 GB; Average Speed:17.26 MB/s.
```

I just want to remove all string between the "," and "/s." I tried many times I can't do it correctly.

Can someone help me to do this on Powershell ?

Comment: A bit unclear.. Do you mean to do `foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'TheFile.log')) { ($line -split ',')[0] }` ?? If not, please add an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its the opposite, the desired output is for exemple : 5.23 GB; Average Speed:17.26 MB/s. Thank you i put 1 to the [0] and it is what i want. Another question can i use the size like the 5,23 GB and do some math to get % ?

Comment: In that case `foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'TheFile.log')) { ($line -split ',')[-1] }`. With `[-1]` you are referring to the last item in the array

Comment: Thank you Theo !  Another question can i use the size like the 5,23 GB and do some math to get % ?

Comment: Does the file contain a decimal **point** as in the example line, or a decimal **comma** like in your comments?

Comment: @Elvind - We don't ask follow up questions in the comments. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not only need to get the interesting part from the log line, but also need to be able to do math on the number ('5.23 GB') in your example, you need to do some more splitting:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'TheFile.log')) { 
    $interestingPart = ($line -split ',')[-1].Trim()
    $logSize, $logAverage = $interestingPart -split ';'
    $size, $unit = $logSize -split '\s+'
    # calculate the size from both the number ('5.23') and the unit ('GB')
    $size = [double]::Parse($size) * "1$unit"

    # now you have the number to do further math on
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Exactly what i need. Have a wondeful day !